How can I update a partition table column which includes partition from remote server?
I have two PostgreSQL clusters deployed on AWS in two regions, ap-southeast-2 and eu-west-2. Each cluster has one partition table temperatures which has two partitions.
In ap-southest-2, there is a master table temperatures which has two partitions temperatures_2017 and temperatures_2018.
In eu-west-2, there is a master table temperatures which has two partitions temperatures_2015 and temperatures_2016.
Then I created FDW between this two clusters. So each master table includes 4 partitions where 2 of them are from local and the other 2 are from remote server. So the structure becomes:
In ap-southest-2, there is a master table temperatures which has two local partitions temperatures_2017 and temperatures_2018 and two remote partitions temperatures_2015 and temperatures_2016 which are from eu-west-2.
In eu-west-2, there is a master table temperatures which has two local partitions temperatures_2015 and temperatures_2016 and two remote partitions temperatures_2017 and temperatures_2018 which are from ap-southeast-2.
And now I want to update one of the column's type. As table schema change can't be done on partition level, I have to run it against the master table. I tried to run it from either of the two clusters but failed. For example, I run below command on ap-southeast-2,
alter table temperatures alter column name type int using name::int;

which gives me an error: [42809] ERROR: "temperatures_2016" is not a table.
Since I run the command on ap-southest-2 region, the partition temperatures_2016 is a remove partition which can't be changed. If I do the same change on the other cluster I will get the same error for the same reason.
My question is how I can update table schema in this case.

I guess you will have to detach the foreign table partitions, run ALTER TABLE on the partitioned table and ALTER FOREIGN TABLE on the detached foreign table partitions. Afterwards, you can attach the foreign table partitions to the partitioned table again.
This is somewhat cumbersome, but it should be fast.
